# How can I build an app in Appcelerator that can be deployed via the Mac App Store

Tags: appcelerator, mac-app-store

Having successfully built an Appcelerator generated application for iOS, I am thinking about deploying the same application on the Mac App Store.

Is this possible?

If so what do I have to do test test and what do I have to do to deploy?

Comment: Is this even a programming question? Please go to Appcelerator docs to find great resources and answers to such basic non-programming questions.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. Appcelerator is a mobile app platform. It doesn't support Mac desktop applications.

Only if you've create a webapp you could use a different wrapper (like Electron) to create standalone wrappers so you could upload it to the Mac-Store. But that's not related to Appcelerator.